# Applescript editor camera access

Tags: applescript, camera

I'am trying to use [imagesnap](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/) inside applescript but when I run my script in editor it hangs.
If i run imagesnap in terminal it does the job.

Here is the code :

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/imagesnap"
```

The expected result is an image from FaceTime camera in the current finder folder.

I've noticed that my script also works in automator. My guess is that automator and terminal have camera access in system preferences. However applescript editor does not show up there.

AppleScriptApp version:  2.11 (203.1) AppleScript 2.7

macOS version: Mojave 10.14.6

Privacy settings with test_script:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Might you edit this to add a few details? What version of AppleScrupt editor and macos are you running? The permissions model changes a bit from version to version so we might need to know more about your setup to answer. Adding a screen shot of your system preferences also can help greatly so we can see what you see and how you’ve set things up.

Comment: RE: "The expected result is a screenshot in the current finder folder." -- **ImageSnap** does not take _screen shots_, it captures still images from an iSight or other video source, which are not the same things. Additionally, as the default **PWD** of a `do shell script` _command_  is `/`, it is not going to write the file there! You need to first _change directory_ to one that is _writeable_, e.g. `do shell script "cd ~/Desktop || exit; /usr/local/bin/imagesnap"` Is **Script Editor** where you will always run this `do shell script` _command_ from, or are you just testing your _code_ there?

Comment: What is the intended end usage of your _code_?  At the moment, I'm not where I can test in **macOS Mojave**, or later, as since **macOS Mojave** there is a **Camera** section in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**; however if you're just trying to test your _code_ in **Script Editor**, I'd try testing it where you actually intend to use it and if it works then there really is no issue. Or you could try saving it as an _application_ and then run the _application_ to see if it will request access to the camera.

Comment: @user3439894 So yes the app method works - it asks the permission and  executes. So i can do it this way but it is very slow and ugly. I need to test and debug the code.
The purpose by the way is a little security LaunchDaemon for my own use.

Comment: What are you trying to debug? There really is nothing to debug as `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/imagesnap"` does execute outside of **Script Editor**. Is there other code your are not showing that needs to be debugged? Also, if you are doing a **Launch Daemon**, then **AppleScript** may not be the best to be _coding_ it in. Maybe a _shell script_ would be better.

Comment: @user3439894 I have other code which needs debug info. So do you think that I need to get rid of the applescript here?

Comment: lisichka ggg, If you have other **AppleScript** _code_ to debug, can you not just temporarily comment out the `do shell script` _command_? If the remaining _code_ is dependent on the _file_ created by `imagesnap`, you could simulate that with some different, temporarily, _code_. That all said, it is very difficult to suggest things when there is more unknown then known about what you are really trying to accomplish and how.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes I think it will be enough with temporary code. Thank you. I thinks two methods could be posted.